# windows store app submission stuck in publishing

Tags: uwp, windows-store, desktop-bridge

I submitted an update for my (desktop bridge) app to the Windows Store on Monday of this week. The submission has been "stuck" in the "Publishing" state since late Monday (5 or 6 days) and is still not live in the store.

Is this delay normal? 
Is there anything I can do to get the update to go live in the store? 
How long does it normally take for an update to go live in the store?

This is the app...
https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9N9SZH5KRNNX

Thanks!

Comment: Dont worry sometimes it takes time, as you said app is publishing means certification is completed, so your app will available through deep link and searchable through store after some time or immediately. You not need to do anything. If there was some problem with certification microsoft notify through reg. Email

Comment: Its now been over a week (8 days) since I submitted and the app is still stuck in the Publishing state. Has anyone seen a submission take this long?

Comment: Not too much some time it take upto 14days , my experiance is with 14 days also, but if i push update, it is not take more than 3 days

Comment: If you still have this problem, please reach out to me [swick at microsoft.com] and I will follow up with the team directly.

Comment: I opened a support case with Microsoft on this on 5/3 (after 10 days in publishing state) and they were helpful in pushing the submission through to the store. I'm not sure what the expected time frame is for Publishing to complete, but the case they opened indicated the "SLA (Service Level Agreement) had been exceeded".  Special thanks to Stefan Wick for reaching out on this!